# OpenGL ES 2.0: Vertex Shader compile status result is 0 with no Shader Log Info

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, compilation, shader

Current situation doesn't allow me to use a computer. And it will be like this for a while. I use Android IDE (AIDE) to program on my phone.

In my code, I used glGetShaderiv() to get the compile status, and noticed the status value is 0. However, there is no indication to suggest the vertex shader code contains an error or something is wrong with loading the GLSL code from a text file.

Below are the codes. Note that I jumbled all the codes together so that the execution of the code is as iterative as possible. Meaning the code doesn't jump around a lot using function calls, for easier debugging.

RenderView class:

```
package p.e;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.content.Context;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class RenderView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

private Context context;
private Table table;
private int texture;
private final float[] projectionMatrix=new float[16];
private final float[] modelMatrix=new float[16];
private Shader shader;

public RenderView(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 p1, EGLConfig p2)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    glClearColor(1f,0f,1f,1f);

    this.shader=new Shader(context);
    this.table=new Table();

    final int[] textureID=new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1,textureID,0);
    texture=textureID[0];
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled=false;
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, options);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,bitmap,0);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    bitmap.recycle();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 p1, int width, int height)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    perspectiveM(projectionMatrix,45f, (float)width/(float)height,1f,10f);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix,0,0f,0f,-2.5f);
    Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix,0,-60f,1f,0f,0f);

    final float[] temp=new float[16];
    Matrix.multiplyMM(temp,0,projectionMatrix,0,modelMatrix,0);
    System.arraycopy(temp,0,projectionMatrix,0,temp.length);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shader.getProgram());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.uMatrixLocation, 1, false, projectionMatrix,0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glUniform1i(shader.uTextureUnitLocation,0);

    table.getVertexBuffer().position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader.aPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT,false,2*4,table.getVertexBuffer());
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, table.vertexBufferPointer);
    //table.getVertexBuffer().position(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.aPositionLocation);
    //table.getVertexBuffer().rewind();
    table.getVertexBuffer().position(0);
    //table.getTexBuffer().position(0);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, table.texBufferPointer);

    table.getTexBuffer().position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader.aTexPositionLocaton,2,GL_FLOAT,false,2*4,table.getTexBuffer());
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.aTexPositionLocaton);
    //table.getTexBuffer().rewind();
    table.getTexBuffer().position(0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.aPositionLocation);
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.aTexPositionLocaton);
}

public static void perspectiveM(float[] m, float yFovInDegrees, float aspect, float n, float f) {
    final float angleInRadians = (float) (yFovInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
    final float a = (float) (1.0 / Math.tan(angleInRadians / 2.0));

    m[0] = a / aspect;
    m[1] = 0f;
    m[2] = 0f;
    m[3] = 0f;

    m[4] = 0f;
    m[5] = a;
    m[6] = 0f;
    m[7] = 0f;

    m[8] = 0f;
    m[9] = 0f;
    m[10] = -((f + n) / (f - n));
    m[11] = -1f;

    m[12] = 0f;
    m[13] = 0f;
    m[14] = -((2f * f * n) / (f - n));
    m[15] = 0f;        
}
```

}
`

Table class:

```
package p.e;
import java.nio.*;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;

public class Table
{
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private FloatBuffer texBuffer;
public int vertexBufferPointer;
public int texBufferPointer;
private final float[] vertexData={
    -0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,0.5f,
    -0.5f,0.5f
};

private final float[] texData={
    0f,1f,
    1f,1f,
    1f,0f,
    0f,0f
};

public Table(){
    int[] bufferPointer=new int[1];
    glGenBuffers(1,bufferPointer,0);
    vertexBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexData.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertexData);
    vertexBuffer.flip();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferPointer[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  vertexData.length*4, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    vertexBufferPointer=bufferPointer[0];
    texBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texData.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    texBuffer.put(texData);
    texBuffer.flip();
    glGenBuffers(1, bufferPointer,0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferPointer[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,texData.length*4, texBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

public FloatBuffer getVertexBuffer(){
    return vertexBuffer;
}

public FloatBuffer getTexBuffer(){
    return texBuffer;
}
}
```

Shader class:

```
package p.e;
import java.io.*;

import android.content.Context;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import android.util.Log;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class Shader
{
private int program;
private final String U_MATRIX="u_matrix";
private final String U_TEXTUREUNIT="u_texUnit";
private final String A_POSITION="a_position";
private final String A_TEXCOORDS="a_texPos";

public int uMatrixLocation;
public int uTextureUnitLocation;
public int aPositionLocation;
public int aTexPositionLocaton;

public Shader(Context context){
    int vertex=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    IntBuffer intBuf=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
    Log.wtf("Code",Shader.loadString(context,R.raw.tex_vert));
    glShaderSource(vertex,Shader.loadString(context,R.raw.tex_vert));
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    //check
    int status;
    glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, intBuf);
    status=intBuf.get(0);
    if(status==0){
        glGetShaderiv(vertex,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,intBuf);
        status=intBuf.get(0);
        if (status>1){
            Log.i("Shader","Vertex Shader: "+glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex));
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        Log.w("Shader","Vertex Shader error.");
        return;
    }
    //check end
    int fragment=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    Log.wtf("Code",Shader.loadString(context,R.raw.tex_frag));
    glShaderSource(fragment, Shader.loadString(context,R.raw.tex_frag));
    glCompileShader(fragment);
    //check
    glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, intBuf);
    status=intBuf.get(0);
    Log.i("Shader","Fragment Shader: "+glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment));
    if(status==0){
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
        Log.w("Shader","Fragment Shader error.");
        return;
    }
    //check end
    program=glCreateProgram();
    //check
    Log.i("Shader","Program: "+glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
    if(program==0){
        Log.w("Shader","Program not created.");
        return;
    }
    //check end
    glAttachShader(program,vertex);
    glAttachShader(program,fragment);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    //check
    glValidateProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, intBuf);
    status=intBuf.get(0);
    if(status==0){
        glDeleteProgram(program);
        Log.w("Shader","Program unable to link.");
        return;
    }
    //check end
    //check
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, intBuf);
    status=intBuf.get(0);
    Log.i("Shader","Program validation: "+glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
    if(status==0){
        glDeleteProgram(program);
        Log.w("Shader","Program validation failed.");
        return;
    }
    //check end

    uMatrixLocation=glGetUniformLocation(program,U_MATRIX);
    uTextureUnitLocation=glGetUniformLocation(program,U_TEXTUREUNIT);
    aPositionLocation=glGetAttribLocation(program,A_POSITION);
    aTexPositionLocaton=glGetAttribLocation(program,A_TEXCOORDS);
}

public void setVertexAttributePointer(int location, int offset, int componentCount, int type, boolean isTranspose, int stride, FloatBuffer buffer){
    buffer.position(offset);
    glVertexAttribPointer(location, componentCount,type,isTranspose,stride,buffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
    buffer.rewind();
}

public void setup(FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, FloatBuffer texBuffer){
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT,false,0,vertexBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    vertexBuffer.rewind();
    texBuffer.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aTexPositionLocaton,2,GL_FLOAT,false,0,texBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTexPositionLocaton);
    texBuffer.rewind();
}

public int getProgram(){
    return program;
}

public void bind(int texture, float[] matrix){
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, matrix,0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glUniform1i(uTextureUnitLocation,0);
}

private static String loadString(Context context, int resourceID){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceID)));
        String line;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Below are the shader source codes.

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_matrix;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texPos;

varying vec2 v_texPos;

void main{
v_texPos=a_texPos;
gl_Position=u_matrix*a_position;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_texUnit;

varying vec2 v_texPos;

void main(){
gl_FragColor=texture2D(u_texUnit,v_texPos);
}
```

I will post a screenshot of Logcat displaying nothing but the phrase "Vertex shader error" debug message. The GL_INVALID_OPERATION is caused by the vertex shader status being 0, was deleted and returned back to the onSurfaceCreated(), and not being able to point to the matrix location, as the vertex shader is nonexistent at that point in time.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a simple typo. The vertex shader is missing () after main:

```
void main{
```

needs to be:

```
void main(){
```

Comment: Yep, that fixes the weird Logcat messages. Can't do much with just a phone.